# Trouble with creating Battleship using Java

Tags: java

The following block of code is supposed to check if the coordinates that the user entered are the coordinates of the ship. The ship is located on a two dimensional array at (1,1) and (1,2).

The problem started when I surrounded the `getUserGuess` method implementation with a while loop. The loop checks if the ship is still alive and will keep asking for the user to enter coordinates until the ship is sunk. However, as soon as the user enters either pair of the correct coordinates, the entire ship is sunk.

I have no idea why this keeps happening. As soon as I comment out the loop, the problem stops, but the loop is necessary.

Here is the method:

```
public void checkResult(String userGuess) {
    while (frigateIsAlive == true) {
        if (userGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(board[1][1])){
            System.out.println("hit!");
            numOfHitsOnFrigate++;
            board[1][1] = " *";
            createBoard();
        }
        if (userGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(board[1][2])) {
            System.out.println("hit!");
            numOfHitsOnFrigate++;
            board[1][2] = " *";
            createBoard();
        }
        else if (numOfHitsOnFrigate == 2) {
            System.out.println("Enemy frigate has been sunk!");
            frigateIsAlive = false;
            break;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("miss!");
            // try again
        }
    }
} 

public String getUserGuess() 
{   // takes the users guess

    System.out.println("Choose a coordinate on the board to fire at");
    int x = input.nextInt();                                                        
    int y = input.nextInt();

    String userGuess = board[x][y];
    return userGuess;
}
```

Let me know if you need to see any other part of the code in order to better assist me.

Comment: use while (frigateIsAlive) instead while (frigateIsAlive == true)

Comment: I believe something else is making it go inside numOfHitsOnFrigate can you print out the value of `numOfHitsonFrigate` to make sure it's incrementing correctly

Comment: The logic is flawed, you don't need a `while` here, assume `userGuess` is good for `board[1][1]` if you enter the loop, you only left it after going 2 times in the first `if` and I'm pretty sure that's not what you want.

Comment: @KRUKUSA I just did that.. it is incrementing correctly.

Comment: Also if you miss you get yourself an infinite loop..

Comment: @RC. What would you suggest?

Comment: The loop needs to be around the method call, not inside the method body; because you have the "guess" as a parameter, and you want the guess to be different from one iteration of the loop to the next.

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/260609/trouble-with-creating-battleship-using-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method is flawed :

- If `userGuess` matches board[1][1], the loop will make you increment `numOfHitsOnFrigate` twice, and then you'll change `frigateIsAlive` to false and exit.
- If `userGuess` matches board[1][2], the loop will make you increment `numOfHitsOnFrigate` infinite times and you'll never exit.
- If `userGuess` doesn't match, the loop will never terminate, and keep printing `miss!` without getting new input.

You need to remove the loop, since this method checks a single `userGuess`, and change the conditions :

```
public void checkResult(String userGuess) {
        if (userGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(board[1][1])){
            System.out.println("hit!");
            numOfHitsOnFrigate++;
            board[1][1] = " *";
            createBoard();
        } else if (userGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(board[1][2])) {
            System.out.println("hit!");
            numOfHitsOnFrigate++;
            board[1][2] = " *";
            createBoard();
        } else {
            System.out.println("miss!");
            // try again
        }
        if (numOfHitsOnFrigate == 2) {
            System.out.println("Enemy frigate has been sunk!");
            frigateIsAlive = false;
        }
}
```

Based on what you wrote - `I surrounded the getUserGuess method implementation with a while loop.` - you have another loop which keeps getting input from the user. That other loop, whose code you haven't shown us, is necessary, since without it the game won't progress.

Comment: I have no other loop... so I took your advice and fixed the method. Now what I am wondering is if this entire method must be surrounded by the loop? Or should I surround the getUserGuess method implementation with the loop?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer But you said you "surrounded getUserGuess method with a while loop". I don't see any `getUserGuess` method in your question. I only see `checkResult`.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer OK, so it looks like you want to have some game loop, in which you will call getUserGuess and then check if that guess is a miss, a hit or a hit that sinks a ship. Your checkResult method performs the check for a single ship. If you have multiple ships, you'll need to call multiple similar methods, or a single method that checks all ships.

Comment: I created a game class that has all the methods running in sequential order and the checkResult method is nested within the while loop. it now works.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want (pseudo-code):

- start (of a loop)
- ask user for a guess
- check result for the guess
- sunk => stop / not sunk => continue to start

(i.e. you misplaced your `while` loop)